# Problem with Leaflet Control Layers using Vector Layers

Tags: leaflet, vector-tiles

I'd like to add a Vector Layer and configure it in a Leaflet Map with Leaflet Control Layers.

The code is ...

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8" />
              <title>Example</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />


              <style>
                  .map {
                      position: absolute;
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                  }
              </style>
          </head>
          <body>
              <div id="map" class="map"></div>
              <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
              <script src="http://rawgit.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/master/dist/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile.min.js"></script>

              <script>

                var map = new L.map('map').setView([44.907852, 7.673789],16);

                var baseLayer = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                  attribution: '? OpenStreetMap contributors'
                });

                map.addLayer(baseLayer);

                var config = {
                  url: "https://d2munx5tg0hw47.cloudfront.net/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mapbox",
                };
                var mapillarySequences = new L.TileLayer.MVTSource(config);
                map.addLayer(mapillarySequences);

                var baseMaps = {
                    "Basemap": baseLayer
                };

                var overlayMaps = {
                    "Mapillary Sequences": mapillarySequences
                };

                L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);



              </script>
          </body>
          </html>
```

It doesn't work: my vector layer doesn't appear on the map, but if I remove these rows...

```
                var baseMaps = {
                    "Basemap": baseLayer
                };

                var overlayMaps = {
                    "Mapillary Sequences": mapillarySequences
                };

                L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

... all works fine.

Any suggestion, example, jsfiddle, alternatives?

Cesare

Comment: To access Mapbox, is necessary create an access token: https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-api-access-token/

Comment: Uhmmmm... I don't think this is the problem ... No error appears in log console about this and, if I comment the lines about L.control.layers and its configuration all works fine ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved ... doing a search on the web I've found that the problem was about the layer's zIndexes and that there is a UNDOCUMENTED (!!???), feature that solve the problem ...

Here you're a couple of useful links:

- http://www.wjst.de/blog/sciencesurf/2015/08/leaflet-js-layer-order-layer-address-and-links/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466951/mapbox-leaflet-javascript-pane-layer-control/28467308#28467308

Here you're my modified code that now is working fine ...

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8" />
              <title>Example</title>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />


              <style>
                  .map {
                      position: absolute;
                      width: 100%;
                      height: 100%;
                  }
              </style>
          </head>
          <body>
              <div id="map" class="map"></div>
              <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
              <script src="http://rawgit.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile/master/dist/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile.min.js"></script>

              <script>

                var baseLayer = new L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                        maxZoom: 18,
                    zIndex: 1,
                          attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                            '<a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | map style  &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpeTopoMap</a> ' +
                        '(<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
                });


                var config = {
                  url: "https://d2munx5tg0hw47.cloudfront.net/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.mapbox",
                  zIndex: 1000
                };
                var mapillarySequences = new L.TileLayer.MVTSource(config);

                var map = L.map('map', {
                                         center: [44.907852, 7.673789],
                                         zoom: 16,
                                         autoZIndex: false,
                                         layers: [baseLayer, mapillarySequences]
                                       });

                var baseLayers = {
                    "Basemap": baseLayer
                };

                var overlayLayers = {
                    "MapillarySequences": mapillarySequences
                };

                L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayLayers).addTo(map);

              </script>
          </body>
          </html>
```

I hope that can be useful for others!

Cesare